# Display SQL Print within MVC Web Page

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

Can anyone please maybe assist. I've tried to look all over and I'm not able to find anything.

Is there a way in MVC using C# to display the SQL Print Results, not the data but the output of the sql info message window [like in this image - SQL Print Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KO3sK.jpg)

Thus far I've only been able to display the errors, but when executing a .sql file (by design) it does not give me any other available options.

I start by uploading the file
Reading the file content
Executing the file (which could be a data fix, stored proc or select statement)
and then desired would be the Print output (as if I ran it in SQL and also the part I'm struggling with).

Here is what I have so far

```
                string targetFolder = Server.MapPath(@"~/Uploads/");
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(SQLFile.FileName);
                string targetPath = Path.Combine(targetFolder, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MMM_yyyy_HH_mm_ss") + "_" + fileName);
                SQLFile.SaveAs(targetPath);
                SQLFile.InputStream.Close();
                SQLFile.InputStream.Dispose();
                SQLFile.InputStream.Flush();
                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(targetPath);
                string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
                Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
                string myMsg = "";
                conn.InfoMessage += (s, a) =>
                {
                    myMsg  += (a.Message + "<br />");
                };
                conn.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true;//this line will fire InfoMessage on every print or RAISERROR line
                var b = server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
                if (b < 0)
                    ViewBag.ScriptOutPut += myMsg + "<br />Execution finished with " + b.ToString().Replace("-","") + " errors";
                else
                    ViewBag.ScriptOutPut += myMsg + "<br />Execution finished with " + b + " results";
                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
```

If anybody can point me in the right direction or some guidance I would truly appreciate it.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: That looks right, but I know that messages are not always sent immediately (hence `WITH NOWAIT`) therefore I'd try closing the connection before reading the value of `myMsg`.

And use `using`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Richard.

Tried the close connection, no success. Unfortunately (and I probably should have said this). I don't have control over the scripts that come in. It is given to us so now luxuries to have "Print" or "Nowait" in the scripts :-(

When you say "using" what do you mean? Sorry .. I'm not familiar with this (part time dev when needed) ... It sounds enticing ...